# Change style back and forth

Tags: javascript, css

Code:

```
<style> .demo {color: yellow; background-color: purple} </style>
<p class="demo">my text</p>
<button id="change">click</button>
<script>
window.onload = function () {
var flipColors = query("#change"); 
  var target = query(".demo");
  flipColors.onclick = function() {
    style(target, "color", "white");
    style(target, "background-color", "black");
  };
};
</script>
```

When I click the button the style changes.

My question is what do I need to add to the JS that when the button
clickes again - it would restore the original style, and if it is clicked again it will activate the function again, instead of making two buttons.

I know that I can create `.demo` and `.demo1` classes and switch them, but I want to understand how to make it that way - if it is possible.

Note: Just plain JS, not JQuery etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yup, the toggle() works wonderfully well here. I did create a two toggle classes, and the javascript simply turns one on initially, then toggles the two states.

```js
var flipColors = query("#change"); 
  var target = query(".demo");
  target.classList.add("demo-on");
  
  
  toggleClasses = function toggleClasses() {
    target.classList.toggle("demo-on");
    target.classList.toggle('demo-off');
  };
```

```css
.demo-off {
  color: yellow;
  background-color: purple;
}
.demo-on {
  color: purple;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<p class="demo">my text</p>
<button id="change" onclick="toggleClasses()">click</button>
```

Ah, but you don't want to actually toggle the classes, but the css attributes? Easily done. Try this one:

```js
var theToggle = document.getElementById("change");
var toggleMe = document.getElementsByClassName("demo")[0];
toggleMe.toggleStatus = "on";

theToggle.onclick = function(){
  switch(toggleMe.toggleStatus){
    case "on":
      toggleMe.toggleStatus="off";
      toggleMe.style.color = "purple";
      toggleMe.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
      break;
    case "off":
      toggleMe.toggleStatus="on";
      toggleMe.style.color = "yellow";
      toggleMe.style.backgroundColor = "purple";
      break;
  }
}
```

```css
.demo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  color: yellow;
  background-color: purple
}
```

```html
<p class="demo">my text</p>
<button id="change">click</button>
```

This is pure js, I'm adding a property that I use to check which status to use but you could just as easily run the switch statement off, for example, toggleMe.style.color -- Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

The word I think you're looking for is "Toggle". You want something to go from Active to Inactive and back and forth with each user interaction, i.e. a click event.

Javascript has a function that handles that with a class. For example, the following line of code:

```
target.classList.toggle("active");
```

would add "active" as a class to the object `target` if it's absent, and remove it if it's present. Here is more info on [HTML DOM classList Property](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_classlist.asp) with `toggle` and other methods.

But if you were looking for a jQuery solution, there's a similar function:

```
$(".class").toggleClass("active");
```

And here's the documentation for the [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) jQuery method.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to achieve toggle behaviour using javascript

you can do as the following code snippet

check this snippet

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var flipColors = document.querySelector("#change");
  var target = document.querySelector(".demo");
  flipColors.onclick = function() {
    toggleStylechanges(target, "color", "white");
    toggleStylechanges(target, "backgroundColor", "black");
  };
}

function toggleStylechanges(element, cssProp, color) {
  if (element.style[cssProp] == "")
    element.style[cssProp] = color;
  else
    element.style[cssProp] = "";
}
```

```css
.demo {
  color: yellow;
  background-color: purple
}
```

```html
<p class="demo">my text</p>
<button id="change">click</button>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: thank you for your answer but @kotapeter gave me what i exactly try to ahcive.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
window.onload = function () {
  var flipColors = query("#change"); 
  var target = query(".demo");
  var clicked = false;
  flipColors.onclick = function() {
    if(clicked) {
      style(target, "color", "yellow");
      style(target, "background-color", "purple");
    } else {
      style(target, "color", "white");
      style(target, "background-color", "black");
    }
    clicked = !clicked;
  };
};
```

Shorter version:

```
window.onload = function () {
  var flipColors = query("#change"); 
  var target = query(".demo");
  var clicked = false;
  flipColors.onclick = function() {
    var color = clicked ? "yellow" : "white";
    var bgColor = clicked ? "purple" : "black";
    style(target, "color", color);
    style(target, "background-color", bgColor);
    clicked = !clicked;        
  };
};
```