# Toggle Back And Forth Between Styles onClick() - Switch Case

Tags: javascript, html, css, switch-statement

On this page:

http://javascript.drawyourpets.com/

I'm trying to toggle back and forth between styles every time a user clicks the button.

I'm using a switch case as per the code from [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41351730/change-style-back-and-forth):

```js
function changeColor() {
  let theToggle = document.getElementById("change-color");
  theToggle.toggleStatus = "on";
  switch (theToggle.toggleStatus) {
    case "on":
      theToggle.toggleStatus = "off";
      theToggle.style.color = "purple";
      theToggle.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
      break;
    case "off":
      theToggle.toggleStatus = "on";
      theToggle.style.color = "yellow";
      theToggle.style.backgroundColor = "purple";
      break;
  }
}
```

```css
#change-color {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  color: yellow;
  background-color: purple
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
  <button id="change-color" onclick="changeColor()">Change Color</button>
</div>
```

This changes the background color the first time, but it only works once - it should be changing on every click.

I'm not very familiar with switch-cases, maybe something's wrong with it?

Comment: Use this https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_toggleclass.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no toggleStatus in your html element. One approach would be jQuery's `toggleClass();` or if you want to do it in pure js, you can add a `data` attribute named `status` to control your switch case.

This is one of the possible ways to do in **pure** javascript.

```js
function changeColor() {
  let theToggle = document.getElementById("change-color");
  let toggleStatus = theToggle.dataset.status;
  switch (toggleStatus) {
    case "on":
      theToggle.dataset.status = "off";
      theToggle.style.color = "purple";
      theToggle.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
      break;
    case "off":
      theToggle.dataset.status = "on";
      theToggle.style.color = "yellow";
      theToggle.style.backgroundColor = "purple";
      break;
  }
}
```

```css
#change-color {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  color: yellow;
  background-color: purple
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
  <button id="change-color" data-status="on" onclick="changeColor()">Change Color</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to use pure JS if possible. So `toggleStatus` is the data attribute named status that you're talking about?

Comment: I have added a data attribute to store the current status. `data-status="on"` will make the button with yellow background, and `data-status="off"` will be a button with purple background. 
There is a more cleaner way of doing this by maintaining two classes and adding and removing them.

Answer (score 4):

It's not the switch case issue.

First of all, toggleStatus is not a property.

And second, Every time the function runs `theToggle.toggleStatus = "on";` is always set the property on, so that's why switch case is running only for `'on'`

you can do something like this:

```js
var  toggleStatus = "on";

function changeColor() {
  let theToggle = document.getElementById("change-color");
  switch (toggleStatus) {
    case "on":
      toggleStatus = "off";
      theToggle.style.color = "purple";
      theToggle.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
      break;
    case "off":
      toggleStatus = "on";
      theToggle.style.color = "yellow";
      theToggle.style.backgroundColor = "purple";
      break;
  }
}
```

```css
#change-color {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  color: yellow;
  background-color: purple
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
  <button id="change-color" onclick="changeColor()">Change Color</button>
</div>
```

One easy way to do all this is simple toggle a class

example:

```js
function changeColor() {
  let theToggle = document.getElementById("change-color");
  theToggle.classList.toggle('active')
}
```

```css
#change-color {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  color: yellow;
  background-color: purple
}

#change-color.active {
  color: purple;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
  <button id="change-color" onclick="changeColor()">Change Color</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Your second example is very simple and straightforward. Thanks. So the key is to use the `.classList` method? I see there are lots of things you can do with `.classList` - https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_classlist.asp - add, remove, toggle, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Since `toggleStatus` is not a 'real' property of the DOM element `#change-color`, every time you set the property within the function: `changeColor()` to "on" it is being treated as a new instance- and therefore inherits no previous history or properties of the last call.

you can fix this by declaring the property outside of this function like so:

```
const theToggle = document.getElementById("change-color");
theToggle.toggleStatus = "on";

function changeColor() {
  switch (theToggle.toggleStatus) {
    case "on":
      theToggle.toggleStatus = "off";
      theToggle.style.color = "purple";
      theToggle.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
      break;
    case "off":
      theToggle.toggleStatus = "on";
      theToggle.style.color = "yellow";
      theToggle.style.backgroundColor = "purple";
      break;
  }
}
```

This way, your custom property is 'held on' within the browser, and can be changed and inherited by the DOM when set.

example:

```js
const theToggle = document.getElementById("change-color");
theToggle.toggleStatus = "on";

function changeColor() {
  switch (theToggle.toggleStatus) {
    case "on":
      theToggle.toggleStatus = "off";
      theToggle.style.color = "purple";
      theToggle.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
      break;
    case "off":
      theToggle.toggleStatus = "on";
      theToggle.style.color = "yellow";
      theToggle.style.backgroundColor = "purple";
      break;
  }
}
```

```css
#change-color {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  color: yellow;
  background-color: purple
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
  <button id="change-color" data-status="on" onclick="changeColor()">Change Color</button>
</div>
```