# Create two states for the click event

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change its state by clicking on the icon and return it to the previous state by clicking again.
With the first click, the mode I want is activated, but with the second click, no change is made.

Is there a way to define multiple states for the click event instead of one?

The code I wrote is as follows:

```js
let icon = document.querySelector(".test");

icon.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (this.classList.contains("fa-circle-chevron-down")) {
    $(icon).addClass("add");
  } else {
    $(icon).removeClass("add");
  }
})
```

```css
.test {
  position: relative;
  top: 15px;
  left: 25px;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #6229ff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.add {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  color: #ff3d29 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="fas fa-circle-chevron-down test"></div>
```

Comment: You're toggling the `add` class, but not `fa-circle-chevron-down`. So the `if` condition will not change each time you click.

Comment: Why not just do `this.classList.toggle("add")`?

Comment: Why are you using jQuery to add/remove the `add` class instead of vanilla JS?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change style back and forth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41351730/change-style-back-and-forth)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `classList.toggle()` to alternate a class.

```js
let icon = document.querySelector(".test");

icon.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (this.classList.contains("fa-circle-chevron-down")) {
    this.classList.toggle("add");
  }
})
```

```css
.test {
  position: relative;
  top: 15px;
  left: 25px;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #6229ff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.add {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  color: #ff3d29 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="fas fa-circle-chevron-down test"></div>
```

Another option is to alternate between two classes, to get different chevron characters from FontAwesome.

```js
let icon = document.querySelector(".test");

icon.addEventListener("click", function() {
  this.classList.toggle("fa-circle-chevron-down");
  this.classList.toggle("fa-circle-chevron-up");
})
```

```css
.test {
  position: relative;
  top: 15px;
  left: 25px;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #6229ff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.fa-circle-chevron-up {
  color: #ff3d29 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="fas fa-circle-chevron-down test"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use helper variable for example:

```
let icon = document.querySelector(".test");
let state = "down";
    
icon.addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (state === "down") {
        $(icon).addClass("add");
        state = "up";
    } else if (state === "up") {
        $(icon).removeClass("add");
        state = "down";
    }
});
```